# how to add cursor type on a table row using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
 var tbl = document.getElementById(TABLE_NAME);    
 var nextRow = tbl.tBodies[0].rows.length;
 row.setAttribute('style', "cursor: pointer;");
```

This will add double click event on table row.right..!!!But i m facing problem in internet explorer.working perfect in all other browsers.
   For adding style i am handling this:

```
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var browser=navigator.appName; if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
{            
   cell2.style.setAttribute("cssText", "color:black; width:300px;");
}
else
 { 
   cell2.setAttribute("style", "color:black; width:300px;");
 }
```

how to add double click event which will work on internet explorer too...

Comment: post your doublick event handler registration code, there it is failing probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enter code here
 var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
 var browser=navigator.appName; if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
 {            
  cell2.style.setAttribute("cssText", "color:black; width:300px; cursor:pointer;");
 }
 else
 { 
  cell2.setAttribute("style", "color:black; width:300px; cursor:pointer;");
  }
```

will set my cursor pointer... LOL anyways thanks friends..

Answer (score 0):

Use:-

```
cell2.style.cssText = "color:black; width:300px;"
```

for IE.

Comment: sir i am asking for 
    row.setAttribute('style', "cursor: pointer;");

thats cursor type...